# Fetch API at the Browser

Tags: ajax, xml, api

i'm new in progamming and at here i start learn about  ajax and rest api usage, how make this api fetch run at browser?

```
fetch('https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/bcy/test/txs/new', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({"inputs":[{"addresses": ["1EZTFHruH2aBnfeZwCvqwxoyVeQ7ofss6y"]}],"outputs":[{"addresses": ["155FUrRjM3umyw2gA1bJi3eFbHbAQBahBS"], "value": 100}]})
});
```

Thank You

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking. Please explain what you have tried, and please _always_ take time to format your code properly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.